# Reformatting Text from "yyyymmdd" or "yyyyddmm" format to "dd MMM yyyy" format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I want to convert text from **yyyymmdd** or **yyyyddmm** format to **dd MMM yyyy**.

Example: From **20211231** to **31 Dec 2021** and From **20213112** to **31 Dec 2021**

**NB:** In one column my data is in **yyyymmdd** format. I also want to learn: if I store data in **yyyyddmm** format instead of **yyyymmdd**, then how can I be able to convert it into **dd MMM yyyy** format?

Comment: The *real* question is why are you using a string to store a date (and time) value? There are 6 date and/or time data types, and 5 of them have the ability to store a date. The format of the date is up to the presentation, not the RDBMS. Fix your design: use properly strongly typed values.

Comment: Also, if you *are* storing dates as strings in formats `yyyyMMdd` ***and*** `yyyyddMM`, then how to you know what date a value like `20210709` is? Is it 09 July 2021 or 07 September 2021? If you have no way of knowing, then your data, I'm afraid, is useless.

Comment: I am storing two formatted (yyyymmdd and yyyyddmm) text in two different column.
Suppose I am storing yyyymmdd formatted text in FirstDateString and yyyymmdd formatted text in SecondDateString column

Comment: You Don't.  This isn't even technical debt, it's bancruptcy. Don't do this.  Store dates using real date based datatypes, not strings. Then keep them as native datatypes. Leave all bespoke formatting to other layers of your software; databases are not a presentation layer. Formatting dates like this in SQL is abuse of databases, mixed responsibility, breach on standards and conventions, and a repugnant code smell.

Comment: That's even *worse* in some ways, @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot , as there's not even a consistency between different columns within the same table... *Fix* your design; that is the solution.

Comment: Why, exactly, are you storing your dates as strings?

Comment: Actually yyyymmdd formatted string is coming from API and Its saved in database in that way. The important part is I have to work with that string column. I have no authority to change datatype

Comment: Then you should either be fixing the process that consumes the API to then send that the SQL Server as a strongly typed date (and time) value, @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot , or handling the converser explicitly in the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements; probably the ones in your Store Procedure. "It's the API fault" isn't an excuse for how the data is store, or what the data looks like in the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is fix your design; no arguments, it's fact. It seems like you have 2 columns here, not one, so ***hopefully*** the formatting is the consistent in the same column. I'm going to call these columns `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyyddMM` respectively here, to demonstrate the solutions for both, though obviously your columns wouldn't have such (silly) names:

```sql
--Set the yyyyddMM date to an ISO format
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET yyyyddMM = LEFT(yyyyddMM, 4) + RIGHT(yyyyddMM, 2) + SUBSTRING(yyyyddMM, 5, 2);

--Get rid of crap dates
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET yyyyddMM = NULL
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, yyyyddMM) IS NULL;

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET yyyyMMdd = NULL
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, yyyyMMdd) IS NULL;
GO
--Fix the data types
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN yyyyMMdd date;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN yyyyddMM date;
```

Then you control the format in your presentation layer, what ever that might be, *not* the SQL.